# Combining link_to with render :partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I would like to combine 2 commands into 1, if its possible.

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/logo' %>
<%= link_to 'Dashboard', root_url %>
```

I would like to call the logo in the shared directory and have it be a link at the same time.

How would I write this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<%= link_to render(:partial => 'shared/logo'), root_url %>
```